# How to find avg length each column in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created data frame like below:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
l = [('Ankit','25','Ankit','Ankit'),('Jalfaizy','2.2','Jalfaizy',"aa"),('saurabh','230','saurabh',"bb"),('Bala','26',"aa","bb")]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
people = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=x[0], ages=x[1],lname=x[2],mname=x[3]))
schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people)
schemaPeople.show()

+----+--------+-----+--------+
|ages|   lname|mname|    name|
+----+--------+-----+--------+
|  25|   Ankit|Ankit|   Ankit|
| 2.2|Jalfaizy|   aa|Jalfaizy|
| 230| saurabh|   bb| saurabh|
|  26|      aa|   bb|    Bala|
+----+--------+-----+--------+
```

I want find each column avg length for all comuns i.e below my expected output.i.e total number of character  in particular column/ number of rows

```
+----+--------+-----+--------+
|ages|   lname|mname|    name|
+----+--------+-----+--------+
|2.5 | 5.5    | 2.75 |  6    |
+----+--------+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 4):

This is actually pretty straight forward. We will be using a projection for column `length` and an aggregation for `avg` :

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import length, col, avg

selection = ['lname','mname','name']

schemaPeople \
    .select(*(length(col(c)).alias(c) for c in selection)) \
    .agg(*(avg(col(c)).alias(c) for c in selection)).show()

# +-----+-----+----+
# |lname|mname|name|
# +-----+-----+----+
# |  5.5| 2.75| 6.0|
# +-----+-----+----+
```

This way, you'll be able to pass the names of the columns dynamically. 
What we are doing here is actually unpacking the argument list (`selection`)

Reference : [Control Flow Tools - Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: Thank you for the edit @pault

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just create new rows for the individual lengths and then just group the dataframe. Then you would end up with something like:

```py
df_new = spark.createDataFrame([
( "25","Ankit","Ankit","Ankit"),( "2.2","Jalfaizy","aa","Jalfaizy"),
("230","saurabh","bb","saurabh") ,( "26","aa","bb","Bala")
], ("age", "lname","mname","name"))

df_new.withColumn("len_age",length(col("age"))).withColumn("len_lname",length(col("lname")))\
.withColumn("len_mname",length(col("mname"))).withColumn("len_name",length(col("name")))\
.groupBy().agg(avg("len_age"),avg("len_lname"),avg("len_mname"),avg("len_name")).show()
```

Result:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
|avg(len_age)|avg(len_lname)|avg(len_mname)|avg(len_name)|
+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
|         2.5|           5.5|          2.75|          6.0|
+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: hi thanks for quick reply,can please suggest dynamic passing column names , in my original problem i have so many  columns..here i have mentioned only some columns...if possible please explain with UDF.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala can be done in this way, guess, can be converted to Python by author:

```
val averageColumnList = List("age", "lname", "mname", "name")
val columns = averageColumnList.map(name => avg(length(col(name))))
val result = df.select(columns: _*)
```